# How to format currency using Google App Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a google sheet that has 16 fields that auto populate into a google doc template. 5 of the fields are currency fields that I would like to show as $USD on the google doc.

The number formatting could vary so I'm looking for a solution that would work for formatting a wide range of numbers (ex $xx.xx - $x,xxx,xxx.xx)

```
    if (row [13] == 'SPA'){
      const copySPA_CO = spaCOTemplate.makeCopy(`FY25_CO_${row[13]}-${row[4]}-${row[14]}`, destinationFolder);
      const docSPA_CO = DocumentApp.openById(copySPA_CO.getId());
      const body = docSPA_CO.getBody();
      const friendlyDate = new Date(row[6]).toLocaleDateString();
      const friendlyDate2 = new Date(row[7]).toLocaleDateString();
      
      //Adding info from the spreadsheet to the SPA
      body.replaceText('{{CO_NUMBER_1}}', row[2]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_NUMBER_1}}', row[3]);
      body.replaceText('{{CO_NUMBER_2}}', row[2]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_NUMBER_2}}', row[3]);
      body.replaceText('{{SUPPLIER}}', row[4]);
      body.replaceText('{{SUPPLIER_ADDRESS}}', row[5]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_START_DATE}}',friendlyDate);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_NUMBER_3}}', row [3]);
      body.replaceText('{{DESCRIPTION_OF_CHANGE}}', row [8]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_END_DATE}}', friendlyDate2);
      body.replaceText('{{CO_AMOUNT_1}}', row[10]);
      body.replaceText('{{CO_AMOUNT_1}}', Utilities.formatString("$%'.2f", row [10]));
      body.replaceText('{{PO_AMOUNT_1}}', row [9]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_AMOUNT_NEW_1}}', row [11]);
      body.replaceText('{{CO_AMOUNT_2}}', row [10]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_AMOUNT_NEW_2}}', row[11]);
      body.replaceText('{{PO_NUMBER_4}}', row[3]);
      
      docSPA_CO.saveAndClose();
      const urlSPA_CO = docSPA_CO.getUrl();
      sheet.getRange(index + 1,16).setValue(urlSPA_CO);
      } else {
        return;
```

I've tried `body.replaceText('{{CO_AMOUNT_1}}', Utilities.formatString("$%'.2f", row [10]));` but that's not a very flexible solution.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to help correctly understand your question, can you provide the information about your Spreadsheet and Document with the input and output situations? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I think  you may have to consider using a method that returns a  rangeElement that can be used to find a parent container that has a setAttributes method.  Something like body.findText()

Comment: May be this a super silly comment, but if you get the values of your sheet not by using .getValues() but .getDisplayValues() and the data in the sheet si formated as you wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library available with javascript called `Intl`.

Try this:

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    // Format the price above to USD using the locale, style, and currency.
    let USDollar = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
    });
    let price = 10000;
    console.log(USDollar.format(price));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
6:04:04 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:04:06 AM  Info    $10,000.00
6:04:05 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Format number as currency](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-format-number-as-currency-in-javascript-one-line-of-code/)
- [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)